# Proving inequality involving trig functions

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, positive-definite, parabolic-pde

I am currently trying to prove the stability of a numerical method applied to the PDE $$u_{t} = au_{xx} + 2bu_{xy} + cu_{yy}, $$
where $a, c >0$, and $ac \geq b^2$. I decided to use Crank-Nicolson, and I'm fairly confident that my analysis up until this point is correct, and should be irrelevant to my question. As the final step I need to prove the inequality \begin{align*}a\sin^2(\theta) + c\sin^2(\phi) + 2b\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) \cos(\phi) \geq 0,  \end{align*}

for all $\theta, \phi \in \mathbb{R}$, which would suggest that the method is unconditionally stable. 
I've tried plugging in various values of $a,b,c$ into the inequality and graphing the solution, and it seems to be true for all $\theta$ and $\phi$. Am I missing some obvious trig identity? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: start with the inequality

$$a\sin^2(\theta) + c\sin^2(\phi) + 2\lambda\sqrt{ac}\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\ge0$$
valid for any real $|\lambda|\le1$.

Comment: Got it. Take $\lambda = \cos (\theta) \cos(\phi)$, and since $\left| b \right| \leq \sqrt{ac}$, $$a \sin^2(\theta) + c \sin^2(\phi) + 2b \lambda \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) \geq 0.$$ Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you got it. I would write directly $\lambda=\frac{b\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)}{\sqrt{ac}}\implies |\lambda|\le1$. You're welcome!